# 4x4 Matrix Visualized as a Cartesian Coordinate System

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm reading [this](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/computing-pixel-coordinates-of-3d-point/mathematics-computing-2d-coordinates-of-3d-points) text on computer graphics, and came across the following section.

[image]

The 4x4 homogenous matrix I'm accustomed to looks like this

$\begin{bmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & t_{14} \\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & t_{24} \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & t_{34} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Where the $r_{11}$ through $r_{33}$ define a 3x3 rotation matrix, and $t_{14}$, $t_{24}$, and $t_{34}$ define a 3x1 translation vector.

I'm also familiar with the "change of coordinates" matrix. Suppose we have vector spaces A and B in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I can use the following matrix to take a vector in B, to a vector in A.

$P_{A \leftarrow B} = \begin{bmatrix} [b_1]_A & [b_2]_A & [b_3]_A\end{bmatrix}$

where $[b_i]_A$ is the i-th basis vector of B in A-coordinates.

Given this information, I'm trying to interpret how the *rows* of a 4x4 matrix represent the x-axis, y-axis, z-axis, and translation.

Comment: For one thing, that text represents points by _row_ vectors, so transformations involve post-multiplying by a matrix, which is thus the transpose of what you’re used to.

Comment: Got it, can’t believe I missed that detail. Thank you so much!